# Windows 2008 R2 AD-FS 2.0 Configure Error (.NET Framework)

Tags: windows-server-2008-r2, adfs, dotnet-framework, microsoft-dynamics-crm

I have been trying to configure my Windows server 2008 R2 machine for the last 3 days now just so that mobile clients can access an in-house installation of MS Dynamics CRM 2013 !

After MUCH reading and many fall downs I now know I have to install and setup AD-FS and then ultimately IFD.

I have added the AD-FS role from the server manager but could never get this to work with the CRM. I later found out that the AD-FS version that ships with 2008 R2 is 1.0, which apparently is no good. I need 2.0 !

I downloaded and installed AD-FS 2, it seemed to install without problem (this is where the problems start).

I open the AD-FS tool and click the link to configure and BOOM, I get an error stating it need .NET Framework 3.5 installed... wtf !?! I know this is already installed on this machine by default, by anyway I check in the features... sure enough, its there. I have ran other tools to check the installation and all seems fine.

I am now pulling out may hair after 3 days of this crap. I just cant figure out whats wrong and I only found one result on google which basically just has one follow up to a guys post which asks him to check his .NET Framework installation.

I have tried to un-install and install many times, but same problem.

I was hoping someone here could help me out of this jam.

Thanks guys !

Comment: After 3 days of reading, trying and failing I have decided to update my Windows 2008 R2 server with Windows 2012 R2 in the hope the newer version of AD-FS will work OOB. I know it was drastic, but I couldn't take anymore. I'll leave this Q open in case anyone ever finds out why that error was shown.